# Add missing dates in the column in a PySpark data frame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, date, pyspark

I need to insert additional missing entries into a PySpark data frame where dates are final day of a quarter.

| ID | Date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-03-31 | 1 |
| 1 | 2018-06-30 | 8 |
| 1 | 2018-12-31 | 1 |
| 1 | 2019-06-30 | 2 |

I need the output to look like this:

| ID | Date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018-03-31 | 1 |
| 1 | 2018-06-30 | 8 |
| 1 | 2018-09-30 | Null |
| 1 | 2018-12-31 | 1 |
| 1 | 2019-06-30 | Null |
| 1 | 2019-06-30 | 2 |

There are hundreds of such IDs and the number of quarter dates are fixed for all IDs i.e., '2018-03-31' to '2019-06-30'.

Comment: why are the last 2 date rows same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, '2018-03-31', 1),
     (1, '2018-06-30', 8),
     (1, '2018-12-31', 1),
     (1, '2019-06-30', 2)],
    ['ID', 'Date', 'count'])
```

**The case when the day of the min date of a sequence is number 31**

```py
min_date = df.agg(F.min('Date')).head()[0]
max_date = df.agg(F.max('Date')).head()[0]

df = (df
    .select("ID").distinct()
    .withColumn("Date", F.expr(f"explode(sequence(to_date('{min_date}'), to_date('{max_date}'), interval 3 month))"))
    .join(df, ["ID", "Date"], "left")
)
df.show()
# +---+----------+-----+
# | ID|      Date|count|
# +---+----------+-----+
# |  1|2018-03-31|    1|
# |  1|2018-06-30|    8|
# |  1|2019-03-31| null|
# |  1|2018-12-31|    1|
# |  1|2018-09-30| null|
# |  1|2019-06-30|    2|
# +---+----------+-----+
```

**Option working for both 30 and 31 as the number of the first day in a sequence**

This option is safer if you don't know what is your min date. Everything the same, just before the join dates are shifted 1 day to right. After the join they are returned to the original date.

```py
df = df.withColumn('Date', F.date_add('Date', 1))
min_date = df.agg(F.min('Date')).head()[0]
max_date = df.agg(F.max('Date')).head()[0]
df = (df
    .select("ID").distinct()
    .withColumn("Date", F.expr(f"explode(sequence(to_date('{min_date}'), to_date('{max_date}'), interval 3 month))"))
    .join(df, ["ID", "Date"], "left")
)
df = df.withColumn('Date', F.date_sub('Date', 1))

df.show()
# +---+----------+-----+
# | ID|      Date|count|
# +---+----------+-----+
# |  1|2018-03-31|    1|
# |  1|2018-06-30|    8|
# |  1|2019-03-31| null|
# |  1|2018-12-31|    1|
# |  1|2018-09-30| null|
# |  1|2019-06-30|    2|
# +---+----------+-----+
```

Comment: FYI - month end dates can be generated using `last_day()` function.